# AWS ALB with single instance as target - delay on initial load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I hope that someone can shed some light on the issue I am facing. I have architecture as described below, I will write the steps in which traffic is coming to the instance.

1. Request hits domain name, which is an A record, aliased to AWS ALB DNS name.
2. From here, traffic is then routed to the proxy instance on a specific port (Reason, why I am sticking to Application Load Balances, is that I can't simply point A record to URL/Domain and port. Also, I am using web sockets).
3. Traffic hits the upstream and upstream sends response all the way back.

Note: I am using the proxy instance in between to have a "static" IP address to which is ALB bound. Only IP addresses on the proxy instance are changed dynamically, depending on allocated backend IP address.

**Problem is huge initial delay** After testing with curl I found out that request is initially coming to IP address that simply timeouts, and then is routed to ALB IP address after few minutes. How to overcome this issue?

ALB requires to spread at least over two subnets, but only one is public.

```
~ ❯❯❯ curl -v app1.domain.com
* Rebuilt URL to: app1.domain.com/
*   Trying "some_public_ip_adress_a"...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to "some_public_ip_adress_a" port 80 failed: Operation timed out
*   Trying "some_public_ip_adress_b"...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to app1.domain.com ("some_public_ip_adress_b") port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: app1.domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 26 Jul 2018 10:39:31 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 3700
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: nginx/1.12.1
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Content-Type
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Last-Modified: Sat, 23 Jun 2018 21:06:06 GMT
<
<!doctype html><!--
```

Comment: You can use target group to register new instances then bound ALB to the target group, thay way you wont need a proxy instance